# I have get a strange result when use the Pandas.Series.mean()

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I want to calculate a mean value of a pandas.series object.

But I get a strange result...

code like follow:

```
import pandas as pd
ds = pd.Series([1,1,2,3])
mean = ds.mean()
mean2 = (ds - mean)/mean
mean2.mean()
```

result:

```
2.7755575615628914e-17
```

so, why the computer do this?

thx.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing to calculate the mean, but I can tell you that's probably not it.

Comment: you've got `0` - what's wrong with that?

Comment: @MaxU I got it，thk

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I got

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have got it, thx